# Sync Text objects in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a prefab that has a text object on it and that text represents a counter for the prefab lifespan that increases every second. The script works fine on the human vs computer mode, but when I try to make a host client the numbers are always different on the clients side. How can I let the numbers displayed on them sync together?

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{

public Planet pl;


private bool hasDone = false;

public int timeleft =6;
public Text countdownText;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    timeleft = Random.Range (0, 31);
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    countdownText.text = ("" + timeleft);
    if (pl.get_owner () != null && hasDone == false) {
        StartCoroutine("LoseTime");
        hasDone = true;
    }

    if (pl.get_owner () == "Human") {
        countdownText.color = new Color (0f, 0.5f, 1f, 1f);
    }
    if (pl.get_owner () == "Computer") {
        countdownText.color = new Color (1f, 0.5f, 0f, 1f);
    }

    if (pl.get_collision () > 0) {
        timeleft -= 1;
        pl.decrease_collision ();
    }
}
IEnumerator LoseTime()
{
    if (pl.get_owner () != null) {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            timeleft++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the syncvar attribute: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.SyncVarAttribute.html

```
[SyncVar]
public int timeleft =6;
```

Additionally only the server should change the value. Add the following code to all locations where you would alter timeleft.

```
if (!isServer)
    return;
```

Comment: it didn't work i tried this but it always show the other players at 6 so i tried to make it private and now it will show all players at 0